# In kibana-TimeLion can we change y-axis?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Kibana-4.6.4

My json is

```
{"ExchangeName":"BITFINEX", 
 "CurrencyPair":"ETHBTC",
 "MachineTime":"2017-06-01T14:24:17.099141+05:30",
 "OrderSide":"bids",
 "OrderId":"2685192234",
 "Price":0.09369,
 "Quantity":7.40463042
}
```

In kibana Timelion I want to change yaxis as a price, any query is there? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `.es(metric='avg:Price')`

Comment: ,if for perticular time there are four price values so it is taking avg of 4 and giving one value.but i want all the 4 values not avg.

Comment: What is the xaxis?
You Have two options. create a histogram based on your x and y or use date histogram for example which is better to use date aggregation (default)

Comment: in timelion i want, there is OrderSide so there are 2 value one is asks and one is bids, so in timelion i want in yaxis price and in x-axis time and based on price  we want to show orderside (two graph asks,bids). so i write one query:-

(.es(index=ethbtc_order*,timefield=MachineTime,q='ExchangeName:BITFINEX AND OrderSide:Asks',metric='avg:Price').label(Asks),.es(index=ethbtc_order*,timefield=MachineTime,q='ExchangeName:BITFINEX AND OrderSide:Bids',metric='avg:Price').label(Bids)).title(BITFINEX)

Comment: please suggest me ?

Comment: your query seems to be OK. what's the problem? The average ?

Comment: yes ,for example there are four values of price came in same time,
so itis taking avg of all four and giving that value,so if value is 0 so 
in outputs shows difference.thats why i want all the values of time

Answer (score 0):

.es(metric='max:Price')

Now this is showing correct values